# How could the programe locate the input-box of user-name and password on the html page exactly?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, browser

I'm trying to implement an function that auto-fill form(maybe,some page just input-box and submit button) with python and selenium.

It is similar to browser's auto-fill form: parsing the web page, locate input-box of user-name and password on a page, and auto fill them next time.

The problem is about how to locate the username input box or password input.

I look for a way which could handle most of page,but encountered several problems:

1. The user name and password of some pages are not in the form label;
2. There are not only user name and password entry box, but also have the verification code input box;
3. The name of input-box not only as "username" or "password".It maybe another word.So I can not judge by name of the username input box or password input box.

Some methods have been tried, such as:

1. Password input box with password attribute;
2. The user name input box is near the password input box;

But the effect is not ideal.

Is there any good method or suggestion? How does the browser do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here its something difficult to answer your question because you do not mention any reference anyway I am giving your 2 example image where you can find the most efficient way to find XPath

[image]

[image]

> Hope it will help you to find your Right XPath

Comment: O, I want to find a way could handle most of web page . Not just specific web page.It is easy to find xpath for one page just click the mouse on broswer to get , but take a lot of time for many pages.

Comment: You can use https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-builder/ which will record your mouse click and you will get all the xpath

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to generalize a way to automate all web pages as far as I know,as **elements in DOM vary in each and every page** and so you need to change in xpath locator accordingly.I know its tiresome! uff..:-(
However do have a look into Sikuli and see if this can serve your needs.
Brief overview of Sikuli mentioned in their site:

> Sikuli automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image
>   recognition to identify and control GUI components. It is useful when
>   there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code.

More info:
http://www.sikuli.org/